# Read Excel File and Store in JSON Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am working with a project using Angular 5. I want to read data from excel and convert it into JSON format. Using CSV.

> component.html

```
<label for="">Upload File</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="type">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let csvdata"> {{csvdata.type}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let csvdata"> {{csvdata.id}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let csvdata"> {{csvdata.name}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```